Prevent Xdebug Errors When Not Listening with IDE
I'm having an issue with Xdebug in my local PHP setup. Here's the situation:
I have Xdebug configured and it's working fine when my IDE (PhpStorm) is set to "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections". However, I don't always have my IDE listening. When it's not listening, I encounter errors with any PHP command, such as php artisan migrate, and the error looks something like this:
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :

This problem doesn't occur when my IDE is listening, but then I face another issue: every PHP command (like php artisan) stops at the debugger, and I have to click "Continue" in PhpStorm to proceed.
I would like to avoid having to start and stop the Xdebug listener in PhpStorm or deal with these interruptions. Is there a way to configure to ignore this error when the IDE isn't listening?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I've tested in two different Docker based systems (with latest Xdebug version) and one of them dumps this warning to stderr when user doesn't have write permission log file (/tmp/xdebug.log in my case), which is common in Docker setups. However, the other system doesn't. I wonder what it depends on.

There are several ways to start XDEBUG and you have probably forced it to start by using the xdebug.start_with_request=yes directive in your php.ini file.
Set it to trigger as specified in the official documentation and add the relevant parameter to your querystring (i.e. ?XDEBUG_SESSION) when calling your page.

Thank you. I've set it to trigger. I also have the Xdebug chrome extension installed. When I turn it on and send a request my debugger is triggered. Otherwise not
